# Does fetching an HTTP response code mean the body has already been downloaded?

Tags: java, android, network-programming, http-headers, httpresponse

I was trying to measure download time averages in my Android app and came across an interesting conundrum. Currently, in the method that executes my HTTP requests, I first

```
int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
```

and later, after checking the `statusCode`, use `urlConnection.getInputStream()` to read the relevant info to file.

To measure download times, I had wrapped my code around the `getResponseCode()` line, thinking that in order to get a response code, the OS must have already downloaded the full response (headers and message body) and cached it. I believe that `getInputStream()` then returns an `InputStream` to a local cache of the response that the app may continue reading.

However, when discussing this with coworkers, another viewpoint was brought up arguing that once Java/Android have fetched the response code and headers, they do not query on the rest of the file until I explicitly start reading from the InputStream (so the data I'm fetching from the InputStream is being sent from the server in real time).

Which (if any) of these viewpoints reflect the actual implementation?

[Relevant Android Source, if necessary](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/e810d3b49631329b11440aa5b7a54db181d42ed1/luni/src/main/java/org/apache/harmony/luni/internal/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnectionImpl.java)

EDIT: The following is the code for `getResponseCode()` in the Android SDK

```
public int getResponseCode() throws IOException {
    // Call getInputStream() first since getHeaderField() doesn't return
    // exceptions
    getInputStream();
    String response = getHeaderField(0);
    if (response == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    response = response.trim();
    int mark = response.indexOf(" ") + 1;
    if (mark == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    int last = mark + 3;
    if (last > response.length()) {
        last = response.length();
    }
    responseCode = Integer.parseInt(response.substring(mark, last));
    if (last + 1 <= response.length()) {
        responseMessage = response.substring(last + 1);
    }
    return responseCode;
}
```

Comment: nope. The code comes first, followed by some headers, followed by the body. The body could be indefinitely long.

Comment: @bayou.io So `getResponseCode()` will only get the response but not iterate on the rest of the InputStream? (So when I iterate on the stream again, it would be fetching directly from the server?)

Comment: It depends on the http client; but you should not assume that the client does eager reading. The client can be as lazy as possible, only read what you ask for.

Comment: @bayou.io Interesting. Are you familiar with whether Android will do any eager reading?

Comment: I'm not familiar, but I bet it doesn't :) It cannot possibly always cache all responses in memory; some responses can be really big, therefore a response body should only be treated as a (lazy) stream.